# cannot set the minimal width of a React Native TextInput to 0

Tags: react-native

I am using the following code to display a TextInput component, expecting that when the `value` is an empty string, the bordered area width will be 0, but it looks as following:

[image: TextInput]

Any idea why?

This is the code:

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-start',
                borderWidth: 1, width: 200, height: 40, paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                <TextInput style= {{ height: 20, fontSize: 14, padding: 0,
                    minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 180,
                    borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1 }}
                    placeholder = ''
                    value={inputText}
                    selectionColor={'#000'}
                    textContentType="name"
                    onChangeText={(text) => onSearchChange(text)}
                    onBlur={onSearchBlur}
                    onFocus={onSearchFocus}
                    editable = {true}
                    maxLength = {50} />
</View>
```

Comment: Did you find a reason?

Comment: No, sorry......